# "Enrich" vs. "enriches"

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

> The profoundness of experiences, such and more, **enriches** / **enrich** me till date.

Comment: The choice of *enriches* is the least of the issues here, I'm afraid. This strikes me as a word-for-word translation from another language.

Comment: You might want to consider asking questions like this on the [English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange instead. Also, I think you would want to say "to date," not "till date."

Comment: What @Andrew said. I'm not sure exactly what the sentence is trying to say, but quite possibly it's something unexceptional in another language that would barely make sense however it was phrased in English.

Comment: @Andrew and Fumble fingers- this is not at all a translation from another language. I had to submit an article about "good learning experiences" in a very formal tone, and this is an excerpt from that article which I have written very MUCH IN ENGLISH ONLY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting aside other concerns with the sense of the sentence. If *profoundness* (sic) is singular then the verb form should agree with that, hence you should use ENRICHES.

Do not be confused by the fact that experiences is plural. If each of the experiences had a similar level of profoundness (or perhaps profundity), then the subject as a whole is singular.

But please do reconsider every word of what you have written.